# Umbraco 7.2.8 related links razor display

Tags: json, razor, cdata, umbraco7, umbraco-mvc

I have a document type which contains related links in Umbraco 7.2.8

I want to display it in a view but HasValue comes as false and GetPropertyValue("relatedLinks") come sempty as well.

So I took a look at the node in the database and the property "relatedLinks" is written as CData, not JSON:

```
  <relatedLinks><![CDATA[[
  {
    "caption": "Some caption",
    "link": 1163,
    "newWindow": false,
    "internal": 1163,
    "edit": false,
    "isInternal": true,
    "internalName": "Caption",
    "type": "internal",
    "title": "Link Title"
  }
]]]></relatedLinks>
```

As far as I know in this umbraco version it should be written as JSON (eg. as per example here https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/razor/54450-Related-Links-Razor-Macro-Umbraco-7) and then easy to display on a view using Razor.

Not sure how I am supposed to use CDATA snippet in Razor?

Or how to force the cms to write it as JSON?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using it as a JArray?

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
@{      
    if (Model.Content.HasValue("relatedLinks") && Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<string>("relatedLinks").Length > 2)
    {
        <ul>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<JArray>("relatedLinks"))
            {
                var linkUrl = (item.Value<bool>("isInternal")) ? Umbraco.NiceUrl(item.Value<int>("internal")) : item.Value<string>("link");
                var linkTarget = item.Value<bool>("newWindow") ? "_blank" : null;
                <li><a href="@linkUrl" target="@linkTarget">@(item.Value<string>("caption"))</a></li>
            }
        </ul>
    }
}
```

https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/backoffice/property-editors/built-in-property-editors/related-links